# How can I set the minting price of candy machine in javascript?

Tags: mint, price, candy

I've created candy machine.
but I'm not sure how can I set the minting price of this candy machine.
also I don't know where the minting sol is charged in my candy machine.
it's creator wallet?
anyone who know this, please help me.